# Promise Pending won't resolve or reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

I have an update password function that updates the user's password and delete's a one time URL that was generated. Currently it's returning a null response to the frontend and the variable `updatedResult` says Promise pending so this seems to be the issue with the null response. When I execute the code this is the output. I added `updatedResult` console.log() output in two places to reference it's output: 
Also the code works. My password updates and I can login with new password, but I just don't get the response because of this promise issue.

```
USER IS $2b$10$VBjWX9KPX2dVMVcdFASFSDFbG9XjONHqe0bJDjKUvY/S7/gSC4sPbhIekBTa
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] JSON.stringify(payload)
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] {"id":"5e92133edab88409dc4d1219","email":"bob@gmail.com","iat":1586963845,"exp":1586963945}
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] updated Result From Here
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] Promise { <pending> }
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] Executed 'Functions.PATCH-PWReset-Update' (Succeeded, Id=2fd8968c-fcad-4db0-a5e4-3ab7f41700e6)
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] Executed HTTP request: {
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "requestId": "5ae5c23c-3861-4594-81f3-18de4a8631d1",
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "method": "PATCH",
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "uri": "/api/PATCH-PWReset-Update",
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "identities": [
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]     {
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]       "level": "Admin"
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]     }
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   ],
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "status": 200,
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM]   "duration": 722
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] }
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] updatedResult
[4/15/2020 3:21:22 PM] Promise { <pending> }
[4/15/2020 3:21:25 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000179CDB79'.
```

Why am I getting `Promise <pending>`?

```
var Url = require('../models/url');
var User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://" +
    process.env.COSMOSDB_HOST +
    ":" +
    process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT +
    "/" +
    process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME +
    "?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb",
    {
      auth: {
        user: process.env.COSMOSDB_USER,
        password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
      }
    }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connection to CosmosDB successful"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));



module.exports = function (context, req) {



  // TODO: Fetch user from database using
  User.findById(req.body.id).then((res) => {
    console.log("USER IS " + res.password);
    var secret = res.password + "-" + res.passwordCreated.getTime();
    var payload = jwt.decode(req.body.token, secret);


    console.log("JSON.stringify(payload)")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))


    try {
      const updatedResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function (error, hash) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
          newPasswordHash = hash;
          // res.sendStatus(401);

          try {
            const updated = User.updateOne({ password: newPasswordHash });
            resolve(updated);
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          reject();
        });

      });
      let generatedUrl = `http://localhost:4200/resetpassword/${req.body.id}/${req.body.token}`;

      Url.findOneAndDelete({ url: generatedUrl }).then(documents => {
        console.log("updatedResult");
        console.log(updatedResult);
        if (documents) {

          context.res = {

            status: 200,

            body: {
              message: "URL DELETED"
            },

            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
              "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
              "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

          };

          context.done();

        }


      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERR");
        console.log(err);

        context.res = {

          status: 500,

          body: {
            message: "ONE TIME URL DELETE ERROR",
            error: err
          },

          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
            "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
            "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }

        };

        context.done();


      });
      console.log("updated Result From Here");
      console.log(updatedResult);
      context.json = {

        status: 200,

        body: {
          message: "Password updated!"
        },

        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
          "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
          "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

      };

      context.done();


    } catch (err) {

      console.log("ER1R");
      console.log(err);


      context.res = {

        status: 500,

        body: {
          message: "ONE TIME URL DELETE error",
          error: err
        },

        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
          "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
          "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

      };

      context.done();


    }

  }).catch((err) => {

    context.res = {

      status: 500,

      body: {
        message: "PW Update Failed!"
      },

      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PATCH, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Set-Cookie",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }

    };

    context.done();


  })

};
```

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mre]. Given that `updatedResult = new Promise`, why *wouldn't* you see a promise?

Comment: You're never waiting for the `updatedResult` promise, so why would you expect to see anything else?

Comment: should be `const updatedResult = await new Promise(...` (and remember to mark as `async` function)

Comment: I had it working await and async, but I was trying to not use it. I'm using azure functions and I haven't been able to return an async function to angular yet. I've tried with different code all of which works when inside my nodejs backend and returns to angular no problem, but not with my ported azure functions versions so I had to convert them to .then promises to make it play nicely. It looked like this before I changed it: https://pastebin.com/sXgdjbnY

Comment: In addition to what is mentioned above, I believe `User.updateOne` returns a promise, so you'll have to chain a `then` on the end of it.

Comment: @Andy Yes, you had an `await` in there right in front of the `new Promise` that you did not transform into the equivalent `then` call. Btw, you could just use Babel to run your ES8 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I get from your code is:

- You are finding the user.
- Then updating the password and one-time URL parallelly.

You are getting the pending error because you are not resolving the promise created inside finding the user.

```
const updatedResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(error, hash) {
     if (error) {
       reject(error);
     }
     newPasswordHash = hash;
     // res.sendStatus(401);

     try {
       const updated = User.updateOne({ password: newPasswordHash });
       resolve(updated);
     } catch (err) {
       reject(err);
     }
     reject();
   });
});
```

To do it in a clean way, I'll suggest creating a separate function and calling the db operations from there. Something like this:

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {
  // TODO: Fetch user from database using
  User.findById(req.body.id)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('USER IS ' + res.password);
      var secret = res.password + '-' + res.passwordCreated.getTime();
      var payload = jwt.decode(req.body.token, secret);
      return Promise.all([updatePassword(req), deleteOneTimeUrl(req)]);
    })
    .then((result) => {
      context.json = {
        status: 200,

        body: {
          message: 'Password updated!',
        },

        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PATCH, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Set-Cookie',
          'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
          Vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Origin',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };

      context.done();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      context.res = {
        status: 500,

        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PATCH, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Set-Cookie',
          'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
          Vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Origin',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      if (err.errorCode == 'DELETE_FAIL')
        context.res.body = {
          message: 'ONE TIME URL DELETE ERROR',
          error: err.error,
        };
      else
        context.res.body = {
          message: 'PW Update Failed!',
        };

      context.done();
    });
};

function deleteOneTimeUrl(req) {
  let generatedUrl = `http://localhost:4200/resetpassword/${req.body.id}/${req.body.token}`;
  return Url.findOneAndDelete({ url: generatedUrl })
    .then(res => { return Promise.resolve(res);})
    .catch((error) => {
      return Promise.reject({ errorCode: 'DELETE_FAIL', error: error });
    });
}

function updatePassword(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        reject({ errorCode: 'UPDATE_FAIL', error: error });
      }
      newPasswordHash = hash;
      // res.sendStatus(401);
      try {
        const updated = User.updateOne({ password: newPasswordHash });
        resolve(updated);
      } catch (err) {
        reject({ errorCode: 'UPDATE_FAIL', error: error });
      }
      reject({ errorCode: 'UPDATE_FAIL' });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! But I'm getting an error:  ```TypeError: PromiseResolve called on non-object```  Here's the full log: https://pastebin.com/aBwQU6k0 Do you know why?

Comment: You need to return a Promise from ```deleteOneTimeUrl``` function. I have made the correction in the code.

Comment: It's works great. Thanks for the help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```js
Url.findOneAndDelete({ url: generatedUrl }).then(documents => {
  console.log("updatedResult");
  console.log(updatedResult);
```

You have to wait for updatedResult Promise and you can either do

```js
updatedResult.then(value => {
// ... rest of logic ...
})
```

or wait for two promises to complete

```js
Promise.all([
Url.findOneAndDelete({ url: generatedUrl }),
updatedResult
]).then(([document, value]) => {
// ... rest of logic ...
})
```